# PHP COM port connection with DIO

Tags: php, windows, port

I am trying to connect weighting machine with PHP.

I have tested with hyperterminal it is working fine.

But when I use PHP code with `fopen` or `dio_open` it is executed but when `fgets` or `dio_read` is called, it hangs and does not display anything.

#### Fopen Example

```
exec('mode com2: BAUD=2400 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=on');

$fp = fopen("COM2:", "r");
if (!$fp) {
  echo "Uh-oh. Port not opened.";
} else {
  echo fgets($fp);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

#### DIO Example

```
exec('mode COM2: baud=2400 data=8 stop=1 parity=n xon=off to=on');
$fd = dio_open('COM2:', O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK, 0644);
echo dio_read($fd, 256);
```

I'm unable with my tries of both ways to gather any useful output.

Do I require `inpout32.dll` file to connect?

And what is role of `php_iol.dll`, this file I also required?

Comment: Without any more concrete description of the error (if any), the exact expected output and the exact received output, a control group of all return values *per each* function call you have in your examples and hex-dumps of strings, this is hard to say.

Comment: And for doubts about `php_iol.dll` and it's dependency DLLs, please see the vendor documentation. It's not clear what your doubts are and more importantly why you have doubts, in what in concrete, what did happen that you got those "doubts" etc. Also things like *"I tried all options"* is not saying anything specific. So if you want an unspecific answer, go on that way, however if not, make your question more concrete. Especially as you're operating in a very specific domain here.

Comment: I also do not see that you use any code related to [`php_iol.dll`](http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/36224-extension-input-output-library-acess-direct-port-parallel-et-serie) in your question. With that and/or with DIO you might have luck if properly used, with `fopen` you're out of luck reading COM ports on windows. I've also added an answer saying that.

Comment: **You should not use `PHP` in combination with fuuu Windows!** It's a miracle, that PHP still works for Windows ...

Comment: Thank you for reply.. Actually few days back when I tried to connect weighing machine with system and use the same code to read COM port, I was successfully able to read the port. But unfortunately I format my system after that and then now I tried the same code but not able to read COM port. I am using PHP 5.3.2 and I think because of inpout32.dll file I am not able to read the port. But I am not sure where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 2):

PHP can not read from serial ports under Windows. This is not the case on a Linux system, on which there is no problem to reading from COM ports with the common PHP filesystem functions.

Those filesystem functions are also the preferred ways to do in regard of the [DIO extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/dio):

> The use of the DIO functions should 
>   be considered only when direct control of a device is needed. 
>   In all other cases, the standard filesystem functions are 
>   more than adequate.

As you report your DIO example as "non-working", you need to keep track of errors. See:

- [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Next to that you need to find a working POSIX example first, as DIO is not hyperterminal but POSIX style.

Alternatively some software exists to proxy a COM port through network (for example GPL'ed [serproxy](http://freecode.com/projects/serproxy)). This might solve you integration problem with your operating system, however I'm pretty sure you're out of luck.

Compare with:

- [How to Read RS232 Serial Port in PHP like this QBasic Program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3226979/367456) (Jul 2010)
- [Reading COM (Serial Modem) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6370176/367456) (Jun 2011)
- [Giving PHP permission to access COM port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9227219/367456) (Feb 2012) - writing only

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Actually few days back when I tried to connect weighing machine with system and use the same code to read COM port, I was successfully able to read the port. But unfortunately I format my system after that and then now I tried the same code but not able to read COM port. I am using PHP 5.3.2 and I think because of inpout32.dll file I am not able to read the port. But I tired many versions of inpout32.dll. I have downloaded different versions from net... But I am not able to read... Could you please help me... we really require this inpout32.dll file.

Comment: Reading does not work on windows regardless what you try. The library that makes use of inpout.dll might work, however it's quite old. You would need a binary compatible version. I don't think you get this easily to run nowadays on windows.